# How do I calculate the volume in square yards for the attached image?

Tags: geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ORMF.png)

By looking at the link above to see the picture, how do I calculate the volume in square yards?

Comment: How shall we interpret $\sqrt{60^2+24^2}\approx64.622\not\approx62\>$?

Answer (score 0):

First, you DON'T "calculate volume in square yards!  You calculate volume in **cubic** yards.

Here the sides are trapezoids (two parallel edges, two not parallel) with parallel sides of length 12' and 36' and the other two sides of length 60' and 62'.   If you draw a line from the upper left corner perpendicular to the right side it divides the side into a rectangle with base of length 60' and height 12' so area 60(12)= 720 square feet.  The triangle has base of length 60' and height 36- 12= 24' so area (1/2)(60)(24)= 30(24)= 720 square feet.  So the total area of side is 720+ 720= 1440 square feet.

Finally, to get the volume multiply by the 72 feet length.

The volume is 1440(72) cubic feet.  You want cubic yards.  One cubic yard is 27 cubic feet so divide that by 27.  (72 is 8*9 and 27 is 3*9 so 1440(72)/27= 1440*8/3.)

Comment: You are assuming that the vertical sides (lengths 12 and 36) are perpendicular to the side of length 60. That does not match with the side length of 62, a number which you have not used (the lengths 60,24,62 do not make a right-angled triangle).